# message=Address in mailbox given [AKIAQ5NIGV4UVXS6AHUF] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, amazon-ses

I'm trying to implement Amazon SES service to my application developed using Symfony 3.4, Showing an error

```
class=Swift_RfcComplianceException
message=Address in mailbox given [AKIAQ5NIGV4UVXS6AHUF] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.
```

I check with the SMTP credentials other ways it is working perfectly fine.

But getting the above error on Symfony 3.4 with the swiftmailer

parameters.yml

```
  email_service_host: email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
  email_service_port: 25
  mailer_encryption: tls
  email_service_id: my userID
  email_service_password: my password
```

Config.yml

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%email_service_host%'
    username: '%email_service_id%'
    password: '%email_service_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }
```

myContorller.php

```
$transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport ($mail_service_host, $mail_service_port))
            ->setUsername ( $mail_service_id)
            ->setPassword ( $mail_service_password);
        $mailer = new Swift_Mailer ( $transport );
        $message = (new Swift_Message('Greetings for Registration'))
        ->setFrom([$mail_service_id => 'AMS'])
        ->setTo($flat_owner_email_id)
        ->setBody (
            $this->renderView(
                    // app/Resources/views/Emails/registration.html.twig
                    './flat_owner.html.twig',
                    array('flatId' => $flat_unique_id,
                    'associationID'=>$association_unique_id,
                    'url'=>$url,
                    'otp'=>$otp_passcode)
                    ),
            'text/html'
            );
        // Send the message to customer
        $res = $mailer->send ( $message );
```

Please Help me fix from this issue.

Comment: The error means the email address used is not valid for RFC 2822 requirements. Have you checked it?

Comment: it is valid, I tried with core php with phpmailer it's  working fine with no issues

Comment: in amazon SES service they will provide `Smtp Username`, that has been added

Comment: Change`->setFrom([$mail_service_id => 'AMS'])` by `->setFrom(["noreply@mydomain.com" => 'AMS'])` or some RFC 2822 compatible email

Comment: @SilvioQ I tried but it won't work still the same issue

Comment: Check https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/messages.html#quick-reference May be `$flat_owner_email_id` is an invalid email?

Comment: If you haven't already, try to double quote all your strings in your `parameters.yml` file, and clear your cache

Comment: @tchap Thanks,  I tried but getting this kind of error `message=Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Swift_Mime_Grammar could not be converted to string` after adding double quote all strings `parameters.yml`

Comment: help me out from this still I can't get solution for this issue

Comment: I'm facing the same issue in laravel. Did you get any solution for this? @K_P

Comment: @NishitModi have you found any solution?